# Swapping key value of Object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to swap key and value of object.
I have written code on js fiddle Please check the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PravinKottawar/o1dcaw8j/)

There is no output 
I am using following write code to html

```
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = out;
```

Can some one please tell me where I am  making mistake ?

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: check on the js fiddle link attached or visit  http://jsfiddle.net/PravinKottawar/o1dcaw8j/

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"

Comment: I have given complete code on js fiddle link . I have also said that I am not able to print any data . I am trying to swap key and value and display it

Comment: When the link rots, this question will be totally useless for the future visitors, that's why we need the code to be here, not linked only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of bugs. I've fixed your Fiddle like so:

```
var out='';
var car = {type:"Fiat", model:500, color:"white"};

// BUG #2 -- argument should be obj here not car as you use obj as variable inside
var invert = function (obj) {

  var new_obj = {};

  for (var prop in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        var value = obj[prop];
      new_obj[value] = prop;
    }
  }

  // BUG #3 need to return the new_obj  
  return new_obj;
};


// BUG #1 -- need to pass car to invert() here! 
for (var value in invert(car)) {
  out += value + ' ';
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = out;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o1dcaw8j/2/

Comment: Thank you for your help . I am trying to swap key and value and put those in new_obj . Still its not working I am printing original object only Can you please help

Comment: @user1121210 Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/o1dcaw8j/6/ -- it might clear things up for you.

Comment: @user1121210 Great! You can also use `Object.keys(car)` to get the keys of car. Just an FYI if you're trying to get keys instead of values.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest two solutions
Vanilla JavaScript

```js
const objData = {
  type:"Fiat",
  model:500,
  color:"white"
}

// For
let swapObj = {}
for ( let ep in objData){
  swapObj.[objData[ep]] = ep;
}
console.log( swapObj );


// .reduce
const swapObj2 = Object.keys( objData ).reduce(function(obj, key) {
  obj[ objData[key] ] = key;
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log( swapObj2 );
```